# jQuery - How to filter rows onclick?

Tags: jquery, class, filter, html-table, row

I'm trying to figure out how to filter a table based on the row class when I click a button.  I've been looking at various jquery plugins, but none of them seem to do what I need it to do.  Some have textboxes that filter, etc., and I've tried adapting the code but frankly, I'm just making a great big mess...  Help? I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr class="dr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="dr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="sr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="mr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="mr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="dr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="dr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="sr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="sr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="sr"><td>data</td></tr>
<tr class="sr"><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I have three buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="filterdr" /> <!-- clicking this will only show rows with dr class -->
<input type="button" name="filtersr" /> <!-- clicking this will only show rows with sr class -->
<input type="button" name="filtermr" /> <!-- clicking this will only show rows with mr class -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like below respectively for each button click, it should work out.

```
$("tr:not(.dr)").hide();
$("tr.dr").show();
```

IE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button[name='filterdr']").click(function(){
        $("tr:not(.dr)").hide();
        $("tr.dr").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function()
{
    $('tr').hide()
        .filter('.' + this.name.replace(/filter/, '')).show();
});
```

Adding an ID to your table would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="filterdr" /> <!-- clicking this will only show rows with dr class -->
<input type="button" id="filtersr" /> <!-- clicking this will only show rows with sr class -->
<input type="button" id="filtermr" /> <!-- clicking this will only show rows with mr class -->
```

JQuery:

```
$('#filterdr').click(function() { 
   $('table tr').hide();
   $('table tr.dr').show();
});
```

and You do the same for the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) does exactly what you need:

- Column or row filtering
- Event Handling for on row creation
- Filtering for all columns from a single Search textbox
- Multicolumn sorting
- Editable Rows

I've used this on production projects and some cases I've elected to use DataTables over Telerik RadGrad.  It's very flexible and great for RIA.